# After first click_event was fired, the second click_event does not fire

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two linkbuttons which are added dynamically depending on conditions, whether to display one or another. These buttons have events also.

Firstly displayed button's event fires, but when conditions change and second button displayed, it's event does not fire.

source code:

```
    //conditions
    bool wantToChangeBlogPost = false;
    string textBoxOnChangeID = "";

    protected void displayBlogPost()
    {
        SomeArraylist[] arr = valuesFromDdataBase();
        foreach(BlogPost y in arr)
        { 
            string contentStr = y.BlogMailingText;//"some content in mailing";

            //div for displaying content in webpage
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl contentDIV = new 
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            contentDIV.InnerHtml = contentStr;

            //TB for changes
            TextBox TBcontent = new TextBox();
            TBcontent.Text = contentStr;
            TBcontent.AutoPostBack = true;
            TBcontent.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            TBcontent.Wrap = true;
            TBcontent.ReadOnly = true;
            TBcontent.EnableViewState = true;


            //two different buttons for cases, whether or not want to change the text 
                            //of blogPost
            LinkButton changePost = new LinkButton();
            changePost.Text = "Change MailingText";
            LinkButton savePost = new LinkButton();
            savePost.Text = "Save Changes";


                //id 's are needed for controls
                TBcontent.ID = "content-" + y.Id;
                contentDIV.ID = "contentDIV-" + y.Id;

                    changePost.ID = "changePost-" + y.Id;
                    savePost.ID = "savePost-" + y.Id;

                    changePost.CommandArgument = "content-" + y.Id;
                    savePost.CommandArgument = "content-" + y.Id;


             //Add these controls to the placeholder, which is defined in asmx:
             //initially add only the contentDiv
             myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(contentDiv);


             ///////////////////////////
             //  HERE IS THE PROBLEM:  //
             ///////////////////////////

             //Conditions determing when to display one or another linkbutton and 
                                    //TBcontent
             if (wantToChangeBlogPost == true && textBoxOnChangeID == "content-" + y.Id)
                { 
                    savePost.Click += new EventHandler(save_click);
            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM: this event never fires :(
                    contentDIV.InnerHtml = "";
                    TBcontent.ReadOnly = false;
                    TBcontent.Visible = true;

                    // this button is displayd when someone has clicked on button 
                            //'changePost'
                    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(savePost);
                }
             else
                {
                    changePost.Click += new EventHandler(changePost_Click); 
                    contentDIV.InnerHtml = contentStr;                         
                    TBcontent.ReadOnly = true;
                    TBcontent.Visible = false;//initially the TB is not visible

                    //initially the bool is false and
                    // this button is displayd
                    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(changePost);
                }

        }


        //event methods for both buttons

        //AFTER THIS METHOD COMPLETED I WANT TO DISPLAY THE ANOTHER LINKBUTTON 
                            //'savePost' WITH ANOTHER EVENT 'save_click'
        protected void changePost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton LB = sender as LinkButton;
            //CONDITIONS
            textBoxOnChangeID = LB.CommandArgument;
            wantToChangeBlogPost = true;
            //GO TO THE DISPLAYING METHOD AGAIN
            displayBlogPost();
        }

        //THIS METHOD NEVER EVEN FIRES!  WHY??????
        protected void save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton LB = sender as LinkButton;
            //CONDITIONS
            textBoxOnChangeID = "";
            wantToChangeBlogPost = false;

                    //some logic to send changed data to the database to upload 
                                    //datatable
                    uploadWithChangedDataInTextBox();


            //GO TO THE DISPLAYING METHOD AGAIN
            displayBlogPost();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A good resource to get more insight about dynamic controls and postback would be http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding controls dynamically then you have to recreate those on every post back keeping the id same then only the event wiil fire

or if ur adding the controls throught any other method like client side then u can call

`__doPostBack(eventTarget,eventArg)` and check for the id on the server side and then call sm function accordingly